# WP Ajax returning 0, can't find action

Tags: posts, ajax, forms

I've searched around a lot for an answer on this topic, and even though there's lots of questions surrounding this issue I'm yet to have found a solution that works for me.

The problem I'm having is that WP Ajax can't find an action, it fails at the following check:

```
if ( empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) ) {
  wp_die( '0', 400 );
}
```

If I remove all checks for the action and hard code the action WordPress can find it, so that's not the issue, the issue is in the AJAX call. During the hard coded test if I return either `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` is see returned an empty array

Here's the function that gets called on form submit:

```
document.getElementById('contact-form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Store all the field names needing to have their values retrieved
    const fieldGroups = [
        'action',
        'name',
        'email',
        'subject',
        'message',
    ];

    // Set an object which gets filled with the forms data. 'fieldName': 'fieldValue'
    const formData: any = {
    };

    fieldGroups.forEach((field) => {
        // Get the input element
        const input: HTMLFormElement = document.querySelector(`[name=${field}]`);
        // Check it's valid
        const isValid = input.checkValidity();
        // Grab the value
        const value = input.value;

        // If the field is valid and has content add it to the formData object
        if (isValid && value.length > 0) {
            formData[field] = value;
        }
    });

    // Call the postData function passing the wp_ajax url and formData
    // Console logging shows the ajax url is correct
    postData(wp_ajax.ajaxurl, formData)
        .then((data) => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(() => console.log(formData));

    function postData(url: string, data: object) {
        return fetch(url, {
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            method: 'POST',
        })
        .then((response) => response.json());
    }
});
```

The params as recieved by the POST request:

```
JSON
action: jh_form
email: test@email.com
message: Test Message
name: Test Name
subject: Test subject

Request Payload
{"action":"jh_form","name":"Test Name","email":"test@email.com","subject":"Test subject","message":"Test Message"}
```

So the action is certainly there, I don't understand why WordPress can't find it, I've done this countless times using jQuery so is this an error in the way I'm using Fetch? Are the headers incorrect (I have tested this with the header `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` too with no luck)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Shortcode AJAX 400 Bad Request](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/338787/custom-shortcode-ajax-400-bad-request)

Comment: The amount of tabs I've had open, and this is one that's alluded me. Thank you so much!