# Why wp_ajax hooks doesn't work?

Tags: functions, ajax, javascript, hooks, json

I need to execute the Php function from my Ajax form with the POST method. Is there another way instead of ajax hooks?

Hooks doesn't execute. Always returning 0. What's wrong?

[image]

[image]

Here's my ajax.js

```
'use strict';

const url = test.ajaxUrl;
const data = { 
  action: 'ajax_request',
  username: 'example' 
};

async function Start(url, data) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(json));
  } 
  catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
}

Start(url, data);
```

functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_frontend_script' );

function enqueue_my_frontend_script() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script-ajax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/ajax.js', array(), null, true );
    $variables = array(
        'ajaxUrl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    );
    wp_localize_script('script-ajax', "test", $variables);
}

function handle_ajax_request(){
    $postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = json_decode($postData);

    echo json_encode($data);
    die();
}

add_action("wp_ajax_ajax_request" , "handle_ajax_request");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_request" , "handle_ajax_request");
```

Comment: When using the Fetch API you need to send the data as a FormData object, or the admin-ajax.php won't be able to find the `action` parameter. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/338787/custom-shortcode-ajax-400-bad-request

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add a WordPress Rest API custom endpoint
[Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/)

Comment: Thank you a lot!